# How to see actual memory used by variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, memory

I'm wondering if there is a way to see if I'm doing things right, when trying to use MATLAB's copy-on-write (lazy copy) mechanism to link the same large matrix from multiple cells in a cell array.

For example:

```
img = randn(500);
[dx,dy] = gradient(img);
S = cell(2,2);
S{1,1} = dx.^2;
S{2,2} = dy.^2;
S{1,2} = dx.*dy;
S{2,1} = S{1,2};  % should be a reference, as long as not modified
```

But looking at the output of `whos`:

```
>> whos
  Name        Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  S           2x2              8000448  cell                
  dx        500x500            2000000  double              
  dy        500x500            2000000  double              
  img       500x500            2000000  double
```

I would have liked to see `S` occupy 6 MB, rather than 8 MB.

Is there a way to verify that there's no mistakes in the program and those two cells still reference the same array at the end?

I know of the function [`memory`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html), but it sadly only works on Windows platforms (I'm on MacOS).

Comment: Speculation: since `cell` does not allocate any memory, the assignment forces an allocation and a new array is created in the process.

Comment: As a replacement for `memory` you can use [`top`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) but neither may show precisely the actual memory usage. Instead using some [undocumented](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79046-mex-api-wish-list) mex functions it can be possible to create visitors for ,possibly hierarchical , `mxArray` s and check sharing status of each element and [get size](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetelementsize.html) of the relevant ones.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: Yes, an array is created, but it's data pointer points to the data of the other array. They share data.

Comment: @rahnema1: This is a solution, yes. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You claim it's simply a pointer, and I understand why, but [reading between the lines of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html), it may not be that simple for cell arrays.  MATLAB's memory model is far, far more opaque than the name-object model of Python.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: There is a lot known about how MATLAB implements storage of arrays. People like [James Tursa](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/756104-james-tursa) have done a lot of work in this area. If you want to learn about MATLAB internals, look through his File Exchange submissions. [Here is another good read](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation).

Comment: @TroyHaskin: As I understand it, a cell array is the same as a numeric array, but each element is a pointer to an array instead of a numeric value. Empty cells are NULL pointers, hence your doc link says "MATLAB does not allocate any memory for the contents of each cell". This is consistent with the value that `whos` shows for an empty cell array (8 bytes per element) -- `whos` never shows the space occupied by the array header.

Comment: I read that blog often. And have exploited copy-on-write for an OOP solving framework using lexical closures instead of classdefs. But I back to my original point: your mental model and the actual runtime results are in conflict, and I don't think there's a definitive resolution with the information we have other than there appears to be an array creation in your code ... or maybe there isn't.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: Trying to show you that my mental model is not off, I came up with something that actually sort-of answers my own question. Thank you. :) -- In any case, `whos` doesn't account for shared data when computing memory usage, it simply adds up the memory used by each of the cells of the cell array. Yes, the cell array contains 4 arrays, each one with their own header. But two of those have the same data pointer.

Comment: [This](http://rextester.com/QRVZIR73634) should produce the correct result. If it is correct I will post it.

Comment: @rahnema1: Many thanks! That is an elegant solution. It does exactly what I was looking for. Please post it! I commented out the `mxGetReferenceCount` test (it won't compile without its declaration, I guess it's something like `mwSize mxGetReferenceCount(mxArray const*)`?). This test would exclude any arrays that have a copy outside the cell array. I don't need to exclude those, but it's an interesting option nonetheless.

Comment: An easy solution would be if the function `feature('MemStats')` is working for you, though, it isn't for me on Mac with Matlab 2018a. https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function

Comment: @NickyMattsson: That is exactly the sort of thing I was hoping to find. But alas, it doesn't work on my Mac with R2017a either. I fear it might be similar to `memory`, and only work on Windows. I looked through that link you shared, it seems most of those "features" don't work for me. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Before editing the answer I used an undocumented function that has an unexpected behavior and its signature isn't stable between different versions of MATLAB so Here I provided an extended version of @CrisLuengo's answer.

We can use a hash map to store unique address of data elements and their associated `mxArray`s in the recursive function `check_shared` and to get size of data. Note that here we can check for sharing status of in a cell and we can not check for  elements that are outside of the cell and have identical address to the cell elements.*

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <unordered_map>
typedef std::unordered_map<void *,const mxArray *> TableType;

TableType check_shared(const mxArray* arr, TableType table = TableType())
{
    switch (mxGetClassID(arr)) {
        case mxCELL_CLASS:
            for(int i = 0; i < mxGetNumberOfElements (arr); i++) {
                table  = check_shared(mxGetCell (arr,i), std::move(table));
            }
            break;
        case mxSTRUCT_CLASS:
            for (int i = 0; i < mxGetNumberOfFields (arr); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mxGetNumberOfElements (arr); j++) {
                    table = check_shared(mxGetFieldByNumber (arr, j, i), std::move(table));
                }
            }
            break;
        case mxVOID_CLASS:
        case mxFUNCTION_CLASS:
        case mxUNKNOWN_CLASS:
            return table;
    }
    if (!mxIsEmpty (arr)) {
        void* data = mxGetData(arr);
        table[data] = arr;
    }
    return table;
}
uint64_t actual_size(const TableType& table)
{
    uint64_t sz = 0;
    for (const auto& entry : table) {
        const mxArray * arr = entry.second;
        sz += mxGetElementSize (arr) * mxGetNumberOfElements (arr);
    }
    return sz;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    TableType table = check_shared(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1, mxUINT64_CLASS, mxREAL );
    uint64_t* result = static_cast<uint64_t*>(mxGetData (plhs[0]));
    result[0] = actual_size(table);
}
```

(*) Basic data types such as  `cell`, `struct` and numeric arrays are supported. For unknown data structures and classdef objects the function returns zero.

Comment: Gives me the error `undefined reference to
'mxGetReferenceCount(mxArray_tag const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` I use the MinGW64 compiler (c++)

Comment: Gelliant and @CrisLuengo . Answer updated. Please test it.

Comment: `Creating library check_shared.lib and object check_shared.exp
check_shared.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
matrix::detail::noninlined::mx_array_api::mxGetReferenceCount(struct mxArray_tag const *)"`

Comment: @Gelliant You can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and open `libmx.dll` and search for `mxGetReferenceCount`. If you can't find it possibly your version of MATLAB doesn't support the functon. If you find something like `_ZN6matrix6detail10noninlined12mx_array_api19mxGetReferenceCountEPK11mxArray` the function is placed inside nested namespaces as in the answer explained. Please try it and tell me what have you found.

Comment: @Gelliant: In R2018a they have removed the `mxCreateSharedDataCopy` function (see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/396103-mxcreateshareddatacopy-no-longer-supported-in-r2018a). It is likely that `mxGetReferenceCount` has been removed too. This code compiles for me with R2017a.

Comment: I've added a `mexPrintf` statement to see what `mxGetReferenceCount` returns, it does not seem to do what its name implies. It returns 0 for the non-shared arrays, and 1 for the array at `S{2,1}` in the example. When the data is shared with a different array (e.g. `img2=img`) it returns 0 also. [See here](http://rextester.com/THZIA27238).

Comment: I think `mxGetReferenceCount` doesn't count the number of times the data is referenced, but the number of times the array itself is referenced. Note that the cell array has two elements with the same `mxArray` pointer (not just the data pointer is the same!).

Comment: What is the output of the function for variable `a` when: `a =rand(2);b=a;c=b;disp(refcount(a))`

Comment: It returns 0. I'm trying to find information about this, but cannot find anything at all. Not sure if this has been explored. There must be a different reference count elsewhere that counts references to the data, no?

Comment: It may be some optimizations that don't obey the COW rule and it may directly copy small arrays. For a = rand(500); it may produce a different result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170339/discussion-between-cris-luengo-and-rahnema1).

Comment: The new version compiles for me too at version 2017b. It returns the real memory usage of the variable it seems. Great stuff!!

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to verify that two particular arrays actually share data is using the following MEX-file modified from [Yair's Undocumented MATLAB Blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation):

```cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include <cstdint>
void mexFunction( int /*nlhs*/, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray const* prhs[]) {
   if (nrhs < 1) mexErrMsgTxt("One input required.");
   plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxUINT64_CLASS, mxREAL);
   std::uint64_t* out = static_cast<std::uint64_t*>(mxGetData(plhs[0]));
   out[0] = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(mxGetData(prhs[0]));
}
```

Saving that as `getaddr.cpp` and compiling with

```
mex getaddr.cpp
```

allows the following test:

```
img = randn(500);
[dx,dy] = gradient(img);
S = cell(2,2);
S{1,1} = dx.^2;
S{2,2} = dy.^2;
S{1,2} = dx.*dy;
S{2,1} = S{1,2};  % should be a reference, as long as not modified

assert(getaddr(S{1,2}) == getaddr(S{2,1}))
```

This is not the same as getting a summary of the memory actually used by the struct `S` (which I still think would be useful), but it does allow to verify that memory is shared.

Comment: I get this error when trying to compile `7:46: error: cast from 'void*' to 'long unsigned int' loses precision [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Can compile with `mex CXXFLAGS='$CXXFLAGS -fpermissive' getaddr.cpp`

Comment: @Gelliant: Ah, right, that cast should probably be to `unsigned long long` (or better `std::size_t`. This is what I get from copying code online... :) -- thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a way to verify that there's no mistakes in the program and those two cells still reference the same array at the end?"

I would try to measure how much time it takes. Since copying a pointer is faster than copying data it should scale differently.

This shows the difference:

```
i=500:500:5000;
t=zeros(2,length(i));
for ct=1:length(i)
    img = randn(i(ct));
    [dx,dy] = gradient(img);
    S = cell(2,2);
    S{1,1} = dx.^2;
    S{2,2} = dy.^2;
    S{1,2} = dx.*dy;
    tic;
    S{2,1} = S{1,2};  % should be a reference, as long as not modified
    t(1,ct)=toc;
    tic
    S{2,1} = S{1,2}+1; 
    t(2,ct)=toc;
end
B=(i.^2)*8;
figure(1);clf
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(t(1,:),B,'.')
xlabel('time(s)');ylabel('Bytes');
title(sprintf('reference: no relation'))

subplot(1,2,2);
a=sum(B.*t(2,:))/sum(t(2,:).^2);
plot(t(2,:),B,'.',t(2,:),a*t(2,:))
xlabel('time(s)');ylabel('Bytes');
title(sprintf('datacopy: %.2f GB/s',a/1E9))
```

[image]

So there's no mistakes in the program. Matlab gives the wrong memory usage for the cell.

### mex files and memory

So I read this post: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation

In matlab 2018a I cannot replicate the results. printmem works on the pointers you get from `format debug` but `getaddr` and `printaddr` do not give the same pointers anymore it seems.

```
A=1:10
>Structure address = 7d9a3eb0
>m = 1
>n = 10
>pr = 74ed5f20
printaddr(A)
>000000007D894640
```

with this as printaddr:

```
/* printaddr.cpp */
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
   if (nrhs < 1) mexErrMsgTxt("One input required.");
   printf("%p\n", prhs[0]);
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. It could verify that no copy is made at creation (though I trust MATLAB in that respect), but it will not verify that, at the end of the program, the two cells still share data. Still worth an upvote, though. :)

Comment: You mean if the program has time to spare it will copy the data, even if there is no edit made. Using mex-functions seems the way to go indeed. Ideally I'd say you would want to get the pointers to the different cells of the cell array.

Comment: No, I don't think MATLAB would make a copy just because it has time to spare. But I just don't trust my users to not make changes. :) -- actually, the cell array (the example is just a proxy for a more complex object) is going to be transformed by functions, and I want to verify those functions do the right thing and don't transform the equal elements twice. Especially if I don't alway write those functions myself.

Comment: I see. Yesterday evening I tried Yair's scripts in matlab 2017b. The size seems to have changed from 104 to 112. Also the memory address location often just has 1's in it. (ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff)